# How to properly serialize json for invoking AWS Lambda function written in Java from AWS CLI?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am new to AWS Lambda and I'm trying to go through a very basic tutorial example, but Lambda keeps yelling at me. Apparently jackson.databind can't deserialize what I'm sending.

I am trying this with AWS CLI to invoke a Lambda Function written in Java:

```
$ aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name HelloWorldJava --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{"a":"x","b":"y"}' outputfile.txt
```

getting this in the terminal output:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "FunctionError": "Unhandled",
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

and this in the log file...

```
{"errorMessage":"An error occurred during JSON parsing","errorType":"java.lang.RuntimeException","stackTrace":[],"cause":{"errorMessage":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingExce
ption: Can not deserialize instance of int out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@589838eb; line: 1, column: 1]","errorType":"java.io.Unc
heckedIOException","stackTrace":[],"cause":{"errorMessage":"Can not deserialize instance of int out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@58
9838eb; line: 1, column: 1]","errorType":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException","stackTrace":["com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingExcept
ion.java:148)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._pars
eInteger(StdDeserializer.java:460)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:309)","com.fasterxml.jackson.
databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:287)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)
","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)"]}}}
```

This is the Java code in the Lambda function:

```
public Map<String, String> handlerMap(Map<String,String> input){
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    input.forEach((k,v) -> newMap.put("New Map -> " + k, v));
    return newMap;
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me how to format a json or array so that my Lambda function will deserialize it properly on the other end. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your terminal output says: 1) your HTTP communication with AWS Lambda worked (HTTP status 200)... but 2) your invocation of your Java function ("HelloWorldJava") failed.  Most of the error message is about how the Jackson deserializer in your Java function couldn't read the JSON input.  Q: CAN YOU SHOW US YOUR JAVA CODE?

Comment: I added the Java code above @paulsm4

Comment: Is this AWS CLI v2 or v1?

Comment: Hm, seems like it should be working. Can you test it out in the AWS Console? Navigate to your Lambda and check out the Test tab. It might also help to see the entire Java class.

Comment: It's using aws-cli 2.12.6

It's working fine when I use the 'Test' functionality in the console, so doesn't there have to be something wrong with how the payload is being formatted?

This is on a Win 10 machine using GitBash for the terminal if that matters.